# OpenCV in Java, why can't I use Mat.CvType.CV_8UC1?

Tags: java, opencv, dll, syntax-error

If I try to write that code
    Mat.CvType.CV_8UC1
I get the error CvType cannot be resolved or is not a field. What am I missing? I think I've added the correct library and DLL in the project properties because everything else seems to be working. I need to find those CV_8UC1 CV_8UC2, etc.

Comment: Are `org.opencv.Mat;` and `org.opencv.core;` both being correctly imported?

Comment: Show us the code that causes the error.

Comment: Try `CvType.CV_8UC1` instead of `Mat.CvType.CV_8UC1`

Comment: @viktorovich Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to use `CvType.CV_8UC1` insted of `Mat.CvType.CV_8UC1`